# Use Kendo UI sortable widget on MVVM table

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI MVVM to populate this table.

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered col-md-12 col-xs-12 inspection-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-template="rowTemplate" data-bind="source: photos"> </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="rowTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
        <td>
            <img class="" width="100" height="80" data-bind="attr:{ src:src }, events: { click: showPhoto }" />
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: desc"></td>
        <td>
            <i class="kendo-sortable-move"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

I want to be able to move the table rows in the UI by clicking on the user account.
If I add `data-role="sortable"` to the table, nothing works. Ref: https://www.telerik.com/forums/sortable-handler-inside-kendo-template

How do I get kendo sortable and its handlers to work inside the MVVM observable?

Comment: Did you try using jQuery sortable? It is a minimal library and used under the hood by kendo UI

Comment: No, I want to do directly from HTML preferable using MVVM only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the jQuery equivalent `kendoSortable` widget. Using `sortable` inside MVVM templates seems to cause inconsistent compilations. This might cause the handlers to not work correctly inside the sortable widget. See: [kendo sortable widget mvvm UI glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810896/kendo-sortable-widget-mvvm-ui-glitch).

Assign an `id` to the parent `<div>` wrapping the `<table>` and create the sortable object on it.

Then you can bind `observable` methods to the jQuery widget handlers as a proxy:

```
kendo.jQuery("#" + id).kendoSortable({
    filter: ">div.container",
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: function (element) {
        return element.clone().css("opacity", 0.1);
    },
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone().removeClass("k-state-selected");
    },
    change: viewModel.updatePositions.bind(viewModel, e)
});
```

Comment: There should be a bind operation in handlers?

Comment: Yes. it can be be changed as `change: viewModel.updatePosition.bind()`